# Objective C check if element exists in web view

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, element

ANSWER: here is how you do it, since I couldn't get any of the solutions below to work. Basically, you got to javascript, check if a document is ready, and return a value to objective c. simple and elegant.
in objective C, webviewdidfinishload:

```
        NSLog(@"Didload:Check if webview %d loading or loaded", X);
        // The JS File
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UIWebViewSearch" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@""];
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSString *jsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
        NSString *result1 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_ReturnDocStatus()"];
        NSLog(@"docread= %@", result1);
        int RREsult = [result1 intValue];
        if (RREsult == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Didload: webview %d not yet loaded", X);
        }
        else if (RREsult == 1){
            NSLog(@"Didload: webView %d loaded", X);
        }
```

Then, in javascript, in my UIWebViewSearch.js file:

```
function uiWebview_ReturnDocStatus() {
alert ("check");
if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Below is my code. I am trying to determine if a certain element exists in my web view. I don't want to extract the entire html text to objective c using document.body etc because that will take up too much memory. I want something quick. But neither option below works. Please help.

```
NSString *oneString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('moodlez_documentnotyetloaded').value"];
BOOL test = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return !!document.getElementById('moodlez_documentnotyetloaded');"];
```

EDIT1:

Here is my code for objective C, followed by javascript. This code is in didfinishload.

```
  if (1 ==1 ) {
    //doesn't work
    NSString *exists = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('moodlez_documentnotyetloaded');"];
    NSLog(@"exists value=%d", [exists intValue]);

}
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UIWebViewSearch" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@""];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *jsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_InjectJSToTellIfLoading()"];
```

.JS code:

```
 function uiWebview_InjectJSToTellIfLoading() {
  if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
var element = document.createElement('input');
element.setAttribute('type','hidden');
element.setAttribute('id','moodlez_documentloaded');
document.body.appendChild(element);

   }
   else {
if (1 == 1) {
    var element = document.createElement('input');
    element.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    element.setAttribute('id','moodlez_documentnotyetloaded');
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

}
}

EDIT 2: OK there are two alternative ways to solve this problem. The first is to use javascript to get the html code from the webview and do a manual search for the moodlez tag. This method is undesirable since it may take up to 1-2 seconds for large webpages, but it works. The second is to make a javascript function that checks if the document is ready and if so modifies a javascript variable that can then be checked from objective c.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What is the result? Is there an error?

Comment: Seems like it would make more sense to write the javascript code inline (in the objective C statement that you pass the javascript function name). It feels a lot less manageable when you need to handle code in two areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code for objective C, followed by javascript. This code is in didfinishload.

```
  if (1 ==1 ) {
        //doesn't work
        NSString *exists = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('moodlez_documentnotyetloaded');"];
        NSLog(@"exists value=%d", [exists intValue]);

    }
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UIWebViewSearch" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@""];
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSString *jsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_InjectJSToTellIfLoading()"];
```

.JS code:

```
function uiWebview_InjectJSToTellIfLoading() {
if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
    var element = document.createElement('input');
    element.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    element.setAttribute('id','moodlez_documentloaded');
    document.body.appendChild(element);

}
else {
    if (1 == 1) {
        var element = document.createElement('input');
        element.setAttribute('type','hidden');
        element.setAttribute('id','moodlez_documentnotyetloaded');
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: user2104778, I've take this and added it to the Question text. If you want to add more info, you can always edit your original question. :)

Comment: The JS code is adding the 'moodlez_documentloaded' element to the DOM. I can see you call it after you check if the element exists. I think you need to call "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('moodlez_documentnotyetloaded')" After calling "uiWebview_InjectJSToTellIfLoading". Got my point?

Comment: The order of events is there by intention. The reason for the order is that I am checking for redirects that occur when a url is accessed. So by example, a user navigates to a website, which is redirected once, and didfinishload gets called twice. On the first time moodlez is injected and no tag is found, and on the second time the moodlez_notyetdownloaded is (should be) detected, alerting the user that the website was redirected.

Comment: No, when a redirect occurs your old javascript objects and html objects is removed.

Comment: but like I said if I extract the outerhtml from the webview and manually look for the moodlez tag, I find it, yet exists says its not there? As an aside, I simplified my other stack overflow question, if you have time please see if you have an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312488/ios-javascript-order-array-by-element-scroll-position-in-web-view

Answer (score 0):

Actually both statements are invalid.

```
NSString *oneString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('moodlez_documentnotyetloaded').value"];
```

You shouldn't call .value for an element which doesn't exist in case it doesn't exist.

```
BOOL test = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return !!document.getElementById('moodlez_documentnotyetloaded');"];
```

`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` returns NSString not BOOL

The proper way might be something like this

```
NSString *exists = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('moodlez_documentnotyetloaded');"];
```

Then check the value of `exists` variable.

Comment: I tried the suggestion but it didn't work: NSString *exists = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('moodlez_documentnotyetloaded');"];
            NSLog(@"exists value=%d", [exists intValue]);

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: exists is always equal to 0.

Comment: Then your object which has id='moodlez_documentnotyetloaded' doesn't exist in the DOM.

Comment: Mohamed I will paste more info within the next day, so you can see how I inject the moodlez thing in the first place. The moodlez tag is definitely in the webview somewhere, since I can find it by getting the outer body html in objective c and doing a text search. In the meantime, since you are a javascript pro would you mind checking out my other pressing javascript problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312488/ios-javascript-order-array-by-element-scroll-position-in-web-view

Comment: Ok here it is below - I posted it as an answer though it is not one.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I'm not a javascript pro, I'm mainly iOS developer :)

Comment: You may not be a pro but you are helpful, and I have a feeling that my other javascript issue can be solved with something basic. Anyway, I appreciate your help regardless.